# How to change scenes on collision with an object with a certain tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class end : MonoBehaviour
{

   void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Level2");
    
    }
}
 
}
```

I have no errors with my code, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions? The object with the code has a rigid body and a box collider, the player object does have the Player tag and also has a rigid body and a box collider, the scene is named "Level2" and is loaded into the build settings, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your code is hitting this line?

Comment: Yes it is definitely hitting this line.
Or do I have to put a reference to it in the void update() section to make sure it is always running?

Comment: Are you sure the tag is Player no spaces etc same capitalisation. Its not on the player is it? If the cosenis running and you seem sure. Get it to output the tag it hits so you can see what is going on. Get some basic debugging going

Comment: How do you make sure that this method is being called at all?

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that function is being called at the moment of visual collision. Read the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) to check if any collision condition is complied.

Then, avoid straightforward equality check. Consider using `gameObject.CompareTag(“Player”)` instead, which is faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure your collision is working and the tag is also correct which you are comparing.

> Also, make sure you added a scene in the build settings
> If not, go to File > Build Settings
> Click on 'Add Open Scene' or drag and drop your all scenes in  ' Scenes In Build '.

for more information see docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html

Comment: use this script for better approach

Comment: https://github.com/Zain-ul-din/Car-Parking-Game-Code/blob/main/Scripts/GameManager/SceneLoader.cs